# Sorting tabs in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open the following files in Visual Studio Code: `style.css, comments.php, archive.php, footer.php`

VS Code shows the tabs in the following way:

`archive.php | comments.php | footer.php | style.css`

I need to show it in the order that I open it, that is: `style.css | comments.php | archive.php | footer.php`

In other editors, it works like this.

**How can I configure to show me the tabs in the order that I open the files?**

Try this but you do not have that option `"explorer.sortOrder": "modified"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`workbench.editor.openPositioning: right` should work for you.

> Workbench › Editor: Open Positioning
>
> Controls where editors open. Select `left` or `right` to open editors to
>   the left or right of the currently active one. Select `first` or `last` to
>   open editors independently from the currently active one.